# How can I enable "Filter by Email" for multiple end users in Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

Adding this question and answer to Stack Overflow as I have searched and searched for the answer to no avail and worked with Minhaz Kazi @ Google to find a way. Thanks Minhaz!

I want to enable "Filter by Email" on my report's data sources to only allow certain users to view the report.

This is easy to implement for a single user, but what if I want more than one person to have access to the same filter? (i.e. Bill and Ted both work for Evil Corp. and I want both of them to automatically see Evil Corp.'s data and only Evil Corp.'s data when they view the report)

Comment: Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to create a table that has a row for each user and their organization, something like:

```
org    email
org1   bill@evilcorp.com
org1   ted@evilcorp.com
org2   john@notsoevilcorp.com
org3   emily@goodcorp.com
```

Then, create a data source in data studio using this table and enable "Filter by Email"

Lastly, in your report create a merged data source with your main data and this user lookup table. For me, having the user lookup as the left source and then using the org as the join key in the merge worked perfectly.

Now, when Bill or Ted view the report they will see Evil Corp's data but only their organization.

Hope this helps someone!